# Default values not working in multiple select options

Tags: 7, forms

I have a form with  multiple select options.Other things are working fine. But when I revisit the form I have to select everything again. I have given:

'#default_value' = *previously selected array()*

But that is not working I guess. Is there any method that the user can add in the selected list without need to select everything again ?
Thank you .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check it out - http://drupal.org/node/73077